# Modelling time-outs between different applications

Tags: timeout, uml, modeling

I would like to model an application architecture and the time-outs between all the application (e.g. between application A and B there is a time-out of 10 seconds and that between all applications). Which modelling language should I best use for this that it is clear? I don't think UML diagrams will do the trick...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of your model.

**Business oriented process orchestration**

For orchestration between several tasks/activities of several applications  of a complex process, you could use [Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN)](http://www.bpmn.org/), which is a standard of the [OMG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Management_Group).

There you can model event-based "gateways" to control flow of control or "messages" between activities.  An event could be in your case a timer or a error (e.g. time-out errors) depending on the desired emphasis.

*Remark: THere are several third party tools that use BPMN models to generate [BPEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Execution_Language) in order to to make the modelled process orchestration exectutable.*

**Technical model**

If you want to show interaction between applications, but not necessarily modelled as business processes (user perspective), you could also really consider UML:

- [activity diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html) can present event actions and also timers
- eventually, [sequence diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html) could present timing constraints and conditions.  But intuitively I doubt it's the best choice for your question here.

Answer (score 1):

Christophe's answer is correct. However, you can show time out with basic activity diagrams by using interruptible regions and an interrupt flow like this:

[image]

Of course BPMN can do that much better.